# Obtain RGB value of image and potentially move image file in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, rgb

I'm looking at doing a project in C# that looks at an image file not sure of extension yet, and notes the RGB value and if its too dark moves it to another folder for me to look at later

So here it is in block form

Load multiple images from directory > Check RGB value of every file > if too dark > move to different folder. if not ignore (leave in original folder)

I know the basics like get files from dir but checking RGB value of whole picture and then moving it or ignoring it I'm stumped.

I have this code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CompareImages(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures),
            Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "checked"), 127.0, new string[] {"*.jpg", "*.png"});
    }

    private void CompareImages(string sourceFolder, string disposedImgFolder, double threshold, string[] extensions)
    {
        if (Directory.Exists(sourceFolder))
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);
            List<FileInfo> pictures = new List<FileInfo>();

            foreach (string ext in extensions)
            {
                FileInfo[] fi = dir.GetFiles(ext);
                pictures.AddRange(fi);
            }


            Directory.CreateDirectory(disposedImgFolder);

            int j = 0;

            if (pictures.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pictures.Count; i++)
                {
                    Image img = null;
                    Bitmap bmp = null;

                    try
                    {

                        img = Image.FromFile(pictures[i].FullName);
                        bmp = new Bitmap(img);
                        img.Dispose();

                        double avg = GetAveragePixelValue(bmp);

                        bmp.Dispose();


                        if (avg < threshold)
                        {
                            string dest = Path.Combine(disposedImgFolder, pictures[i].Name);

                            if (File.Exists(dest) == false)
                            {
                                pictures[i].MoveTo(dest);
                                j++;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        if (img != null)
                            img.Dispose();
                        if (bmp != null)
                            bmp.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Done, " + j.ToString() + " files moved.");
            }
        }
    }

    private unsafe double GetAveragePixelValue(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        BitmapData bmData = null;

        try
        {
            bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            int w = bmData.Width;
            int h = bmData.Height;

            double sum = 0;
            long pixels = bmp.Width * bmp.Height;

            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();

            for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
            {
                p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
                p += y * stride;

                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
                {

                    double i = ((double)p[0] + p[1] + p[2]) / 3.0;
                    sum += i;


                    p += 4;
                }

            }

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);

            double result = sum / (double)pixels;

            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                bmp.UnlockBits(bmData);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

How do I define the threashold?

Comment: You have to specify what "too dark" means. Do you want to compare the average of all pixel brightness values to a threshold? This would ignore dark areas in high-contrast images...

Comment: by too dark i mean where the image has a RGB value of black or something similar

Comment: Meaning one single black pixel will make the image too dark? Then use Francis' solution if performance isn't too important for your application.

Comment: no that would mean all images would be discarded

Comment: I like the concept of this question, but I think you need to clarify your criteria a little better. This will also depend on the type of the image since they aren't all encoded the same way.

Comment: i have added new code but still need help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up a bit on RGB. Every pixel will have an Red, Green and Blue value associated with it and i guess you are looking for a way to get some meassure of how bright the "average" pixel is? If so you need to loop over all pixels. While doing so calculate brightness of each pixel. "Brightness" of each pixels can be calculated in several ways, you could simply do (R + G + B)/3, or you could try to mimic that the human eye isn't equaly sensitive to R, G and B.

Then you will have to decide how to use your "brightness" of pixel. Mean, Median, something else? It depends on what you want to do..

**Update**: After reading more of your comments I'm still not really sure what you mean by "bright" or "dark". It also seems that you have your terminology a bit confused, you keep talking about a RGB value for an entire image, but RGB values in an image refer to individual pixel values.

I believe that this page could help you doing what you want:
http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx

Also, some complimentary reading to understand RGB:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luma_(video)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space

Comment: yeah that is what im trying to do as the placement of the light in the image is not always the same

Comment: i will explain again, sorry my brain isnt functioning well today,

me and my dad are doing astrophotography,

we were going to leave the camera on all night taking pictures and then i wanted this program to keep an eye on the pictures to delete the ones that say some cloud has gone in front of the telescope

and to make sure it only deletes the ones that are of cloud i was thinking that it would work on the "brighness" as the only way of telling if the picture is good otherwise we have to go through them and manually do it.

Comment: If so i guess you could simply "add upp" all the pixel values using the GetPixel loop sugested by Francis (perhaps divide by number of pixels) and then find a apporpriate threshold by trial and error. Perhaps you could convert the whole image to grayscale first.  
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale  
http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read every pixel of an image, it must be converted to a bitmap. Then you can use the GetPixel method. But, this process is very slow and it takes a lot of CPU. If you do so, you really should run some test before.

```
        using (var m = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var img = Image.FromFile(args[0]))
            {
                img.Save(m, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            }

            m.Position = 0;

            using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(m))
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
                    {
                        var color = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

                        // TODO: Do what ever you want
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i looked into doing bitlock as i was reading up that GetPixel was prosessor hungry. but i just cant seem to get my head around it all the whole program is annoying me

Comment: ok i found a better way of doing it once its read the image and its under the threashold it moves it into the "keep folder" and if not the "check" folder